# WPF: How can I stretch the middle child in a DockPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, dockpanel

I added a DockPanel to a RadioButton element such that I can distribute the radio button label, a textbox and a button horizontally using 100% of the width.

Using `LastChildFill="True"`within the DockPanel stretches the last element. This works out nicely if the textbox is the last child in the panel. But, as the button is the last element and has a fixed width, the textbox should be stretched. However, there's no such property like `2ndChildFill="True"`.

My code looks like this:

```xml
    <RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <DockPanel >
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">in location:</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0">Path string</TextBox>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                    Margin="10,0,0,0" Padding="3,0">...</Button>
        </DockPanel>
    </RadioButton>
```

And it gives me this:

[image: wpf screenshot]

Any ideas, hints to fix this? Many thanks in advance...

Comment: Why don't you use a grid instead? Grid with 3 columns with the second set to * width and the others set to auto

Comment: Yeah, that could work. But it looks a bit overengineered to me though.  Wouldn't be DockPanel-Solution a bit more elegant? It doesn't need all this column definitions.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You need to set [`DockPanel.Dock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.dock.aspx) attached property for your elements and leave `TextBox` as the last element:

```
<RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="in location:" />
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                Margin="10,0,0,0"
                Padding="3,0"
                Content="..." />
        <TextBox Margin="10,0,0,0">
            Path string
        </TextBox>
    </DockPanel>
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: The title of question mentioned 'middle', and the answer moves it to 'last'. So why no better answer?

Comment: The textbox will still be rendered in the middle, due to the DockPanel.Dock attributes. Moving it to the last position in the XML document just makes WPF grant the control the full remaining space of the parent control.

Comment: I tried this, but it screws up my taborder! As WPF assigns the default tab index by the order in xaml it would be preferable to not move the element.

Comment: To clarify, `DockPanel` has a property `LastChildFill` that when set to true will expand the last element to fill the remainder of the container. I think the default value for this is `True` (but you can set it to true explicity if you want).

Answer (score 6):

Accepted answer is fixing your problem but creates another one. If someone uses keyboard (`TAB`) to navigate through your interface, `Button` will be focused before `TextBox`. This could be very annoying on a long run. If you don't want to brake your tab orders use `Grid` instead of `DockPanel`:

```
<RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">in location:</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0">Path string</TextBox>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,0,0,0" Padding="3,0">...</Button>
    </Grid>
</RadioButton>
```

Alternative would be to control tab orders yourself using `TabIndex` attribute. This can be tricky though, especially when you display your control in a collection.

```
<RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" TabIndex="0">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="in location:" />
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="10,0,0,0" Padding="3,0" Content="..." TabIndex="2"/>
        <TextBox Margin="10,0,0,0" TabIndex="1">Path string</TextBox>
    </DockPanel>
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: I agree, this is a better approach.  The other answer is not wrong, but the layout here is more intuitive, as the controls are listed in the order they appear on the UI.  Thanks.